# Power BI Marketshare with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I got really stumped for my whole day on how to display marketshare on Power BI. My data is kind of complicated but I will try to simplify the problem in here, assume I have two tables:

1. Dimension Supplier:

[image]

2. FactInvoice:

[image]

I would like to display the marketshare (Sum of Spend) for one specific supplier compared to others, with slicer and pie char like this:

[image] 
So if user choose Supplier 2, the pie chart will show the marketshare of supplier 2 compared to others. I am not sure how DAX can support this

If the Pie chart is not possible, is there any way to show this concept on the Power BI, it does not matter which visual we can use?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1** create data model like below image
[image]

**Step 2**: create two measures
**Other Supplier = CALCULATE(SUM(FactInvoice[Spend]),FILTER(FactInvoice,FactInvoice[SupplierID]<>MAX(SupplierDup[ID])))**

**Selected Supplier = CALCULATE(SUM(FactInvoice[Spend]),FILTER(FactInvoice,FactInvoice[SupplierID]=MAX(SupplierDup[ID])))**

Create your report( if you not select any supplier then comparison will be in between max id of supplier to others)

**your report**

[download PowerBI file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwo0JwrOBlWjdGdCTTdXSDNyQWM)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this possible to change the name 'Selected Supplier' to the name of Supplier which user selects?

Answer (score 0):

*First:*
calculate % each company spend to total company using formula:

### **Company/total Spend Percentage = DIVIDE([Company Spend],[AllCompany Spend],0)**

### *Second:*
Subtract each company from total % i.e.= 1

**Other company Spend% = 1-[Company/total Spend Percentage]**

Put both measure in Pie Chart.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).